# How do I recover my files and undo a checkin to the wrong branch?

Tags: git, reset

I have the following scenario

- Open file A
- Edit File A
- Checkin File A - Do *not* push to server

oops, checked it in to develop branch but want it in feature branch

How do I uncheck it in from A and have the files available to check it into the feature branch?

Thanks!!
jesse liberty - jesseliberty@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Cherry pick the commit, and reset the development branch:

```
(on develop branch)
git checkout feature
git cherry-pick develop
(resolve conflicts and commit if necessary)
git checkout develop
git reset --hard origin/develop
```